# big $\mathcal O$ for number of prime in an interval?

Tags: integration, reference-request, prime-numbers, asymptotics, riemann-hypothesis

According to von Koch 1991, if the Riemann hypothesis  is true, then the for the prime counting function

$$\pi(x)=Li(x)+\mathcal O(\sqrt x \log x)$$

I am trying to understand how to deal with the big $\mathcal O$ terms when estimating the number of primes within an interval $[y,z]$:

$$\Delta\pi=\pi(z)-\pi(y)=Li(z)-Li(y)+\mathcal O(\sqrt z \log z)-\mathcal O(\sqrt y \log y)$$

$$\Delta\pi=\int_y^z\frac{1}{\log x}dx+\underbrace{\mathcal O(\sqrt z \log z)-\mathcal O(\sqrt y \log y)}_?$$

How does the difference of the big $\mathcal O$ behave? Any references also welcome.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer to what $\mathcal{O}$ means: it means that the function $|\pi(x) - \operatorname{Li}(x)|$ is bounded by a constant times $\sqrt{x} \log x$.

Comment: Najib, I do understand this, but I just can not make in mind the step in a comprehensive way from each $\mathcal O$ to their difference in this case. So comes seeking for your help.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, all you can say is that $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{z} \log z) - \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{y} \log y)$ is the difference $f(y) - f(z)$ where $|f(x)| \leq C \sqrt{x} \log x$.

Comment: what is $f$ in your comment? is this $\pi$?

Comment: No, $f(x) = \pi(x) - Li(x)$.

Comment: yes, as said I understand that for each. what I want to know is whether there could be formulated a $\mathcal O$ estimate which reults for the $\Delta \pi$. I.o.w. what is $\mathcal O(\sqrt z \log z)-\mathcal O(\sqrt y \log y)$ for $\Delta \pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky bit about the $O$ terms is that they do not represent numbers, but really sets, or if you prefer, families of functions. Further, they are only concerned with the modulus or absolute value, and hence $+$ and $-$ are simply the same.

In short: $O(\sqrt{z}\log z)-O(\sqrt{y}\log y)=O(\sqrt{z}\log z)$, that's all you can say about it.